# Embed image on another image in python

Tags: python, image

I have 2 image files.

I would like to embed one image above the other. I mean the smaller image should be embedded on the larger image.

I am not able to accomplish this. I tried:

```
img1 = Image.open('img1.jpg')
img2 = Image.open('img2.jpg')
img2.save(img1)
```

This is replacing the whole image. I want to embed img2 on img1 at a specified location.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using `opencv`?

Comment: No,  I'm not +MattR